# extract a string before certain punctuation regex

Tags: regex, hiveql, presto

How to extract words before the first punctuation `|` in presto SQL?

Table

```
+----+------------------------------------+
| id |              title                 |
+----+------------------------------------+
|  1 | LLA | Rec | po#069762 | saddasd    |
|  2 | Hello amustromg dsfood             |
|  3 | Hel | sdfke bones.                 |
+----+------------------------------------+
```

Output

```
+----+------------------------------------+
| id |              result                |
+----+------------------------------------+
|  1 | LLA                                |
|  2 |                                    |
|  3 | Hel                                |
+----+------------------------------------+
```

Attempt

`REGEXP_EXTRACT(title, '(.*)([^|]*)', 1)`

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Using the base string functions we can try:

```sql
SELECT id,
       CASE WHEN title LIKE '%|%'
            THEN TRIM(SUBSTR(title, 1, STRPOS(title, '|') - 1))
            ELSE '' END AS result
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY id;
```